# 443 порт с использованием Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, express

Есть такой код, который прослушивает 443 порт:

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
  express = require('express'),
  https = require('https'),
  app = express(),
  fs = require('fs');

const pkey = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/key.pem'),
  pcert = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/cert.pem'),
  options = {key: pkey, cert: pcert, passphrase: '123456789'};
var wss = null, sslSrv = null;

// use express static to deliver resources HTML, CSS, JS, etc)
// from the public folder 
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']==='http') {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});

// start server (listen on port 443 - SSL)

server = https.createServer(app).listen(80);
sslSrv = https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
console.log("The HTTPS server is up and running");
```

Но проблема в том, что при запуске node server.js с данным кодом в браузере не открывается ничего. В чем проблема? Код правильный, т.к. в консоли отображается соответствующее сообщение.
Спасибо.

Comment: а по какому адресу вы в браузере пытаетесь открыть?

Comment: `https.createServer(app).listen(80);` — сочетание `https` и порта `80` вызывает когнитивный диссонанс.

Comment: @AlexeyTen да) но без этого тоже не работает(

Comment: Ещё непонятно откуда вдруг возьмётся `x-forwarded-proto`

Comment: @torokhkun telnet localhost 443 через cmd. Сбой подключения пишет, но я создал правило для исходящего подключения, все равно не пашет

Comment: Таки `433` или `443`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen ой, сори. 443

Comment: на самом деле у вас все плохо с пониманием асинхронных вызовов. у вас консольлог срабатывает не зависимо от того запустились сервера или нет, более того он срабатывает еще до их запуска или возникновения ошибки

Comment: @torokhkun каким образом можно решить проблему?

Comment: @Juicy читать литературу. Вот по теме - https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/141553158/ , а
это по верхам - https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/337662/

Comment: @Juicy и зачем вам здесь веб сокеты?

Comment: @torokhkun то есть я правильно понял, что проверять нужно все-таки так? localhost:443?

Comment: @torokhkun код не полностью мой

Answer (score 0):

Это если у вас есть сертификаты или Вы сумеете их сгенерировать

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

это если нету/не сможете

```
var https = require('https')
var pem = require('pem')

pem.createCertificate({ days: 1, selfSigned: true }, function (err, keys) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  https.createServer({ key: keys.serviceKey, cert: keys.certificate },     function (req, res) {
    res.end('o hai!')
  }).listen(443)
})
```

перед запуском нужно установить библиотеку `pem` командой `npm install pem` в консоли

пс: это примеры из документации. детальнее https://nodejs.org/api/https.html и тут https://github.com/Dexus/pem